# Community Algorithms - Adjusted Q-value for disconnected nodes

Tags: igraph

When using fastgreedy.community, a general observation is that Q-values increase as nodes become disconnected (i.e., by removes edges and creating disconnected nodes). Is there any standard method that computes an adjusted Q-value based on disconnectedness of the nodes? I ask because we are trying to use the Q-value as a metric to optimize a network based on modularity as we add/remove edges.

Here is an example:

```
subgraph <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 10/100)

E(subgraph)$weight <- runif(ecount(subgraph))
comm <- fastgreedy.community(subgraph); Q.value <- modularity(subgraph,      comm$membership); print(Q.value)

ordered.edges <- sort(E(subgraph)$weight)
n.edges  <- ecount(subgraph)
q.df <- NULL
index <- 1

for(w.threhold in ordered.edges){

  subgraph.sub <- delete.edges(subgraph, which(E(subgraph)$weight <= w.threhold))

  comm <- fastgreedy.community(subgraph.sub)
  Q.value <- modularity(subgraph.sub, comm$membership)
  q.df <- rbind(q.df,data.frame(index=index, Q=Q.value, weight=w.threhold))

  index <- index + 1
}

plot(q.df$index , q.df$Q)
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by adjusted Q-value? How is it adjusted?

Comment: I mean, is there an accepted or proposed ways to adjust Q (either in the computation or afterwards (e.g., Q - Q*PercOfDisconnectedNodes). So one way to re-phrase, how would you penalize for disconnected nodes?

Comment: Why would you penalize for that? More components should give you higher modularity, everything else equal.

Comment: Components yes, but singletons? The point is you can start with a nice Q of say 0.3 and artificially increase it by removing edges (say by incrementally removing edges based on their score) which produces a better Q but qualitatively worse network (because you are just just making all nodes disconnected). The only point Q goes back down (precipitously) is when you are almost at complete disconnectedness and then it drops back down to zero as desired..

Comment: I added an example, thanks!

Comment: Well, personally I don't know of such correction. But you come up with one, I guess this is easy, just calculate Q, and then apply your connection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82207/discussion-between-souser-and-gabor-csardi).